# mysql index column order for join

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have two table (requests, results)

requests:
email

results:
email, processed_at

I now want to get all results that have a request with the same email and that have not been processed:

```
SELECT * FROM results
INNER JOIN requests ON requests.email = results.email
AND results.processed_at IS NULL
```

I have an index on each individual column, but the query is very slow. So I assume I need a multi column index on results:

I am just not sure which order the columns have to be:

```
ALTER TABLE results 
ADD INDEX results_email_processed_at (email,processed_at) 
ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE results 
ADD INDEX results_processed_at_email (processed_at,email) 
ALGORITHM=INPLACE LOCK=NONE;
```

Comment: How many rows does each table have? What indexes do you have?

Comment: As a general rule you place the "access" columns first in the index, then the "filtering" columns. In this case the index should be `(email,processed_at)`.

Comment: requests has ~60Million, results about 150 million

Answer (score 0):

Either composite index will be equally beneficial.

However, if you are fetching 40% of the table, then the Optimizer may choose to ignore any index and simply scan the table.

Is that `SELECT` the actual query?  If not, please show us the actual query; a number of seemingly minor changes could make a big difference in optimization options.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see what it thinks with the current index(es).  And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in case there are datatype issues that are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Not withstanding any indexing issues, you explicitly asked about all requests that WERE NOT processed.  You have an INNER JOIN which means I WANT FROM BOTH Sides, so your NULL check in the where would never qualify.

You need a LEFT JOIN to the results table.

As for index, since the join is on the email, I would just have the EMAIL as the primary component of the index.  By having a covering index and including the processed_at column would be faster as it would not have to go to the raw data page to qualify the results, but have index specifically ordered as (email, processed_at) so the EMAIL is first qualifier, THEN when it was processed comes along for the ride to complete the query requirement fields.